# Parent view with expandable child view inside Recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented an expandable Recyclerview with parent and child view. When I click the parent view child view expands. I wanted to include onclicklistner to parent item click user the interface. But when I did that, I cannot get the expected behavior. When I implemented the clicklistener inside onBindViewHolder, it worked well. But I think that is not a good practice.

**Works well but not good I guess,**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfitabilityRegionalAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProfitabilityParentData sData = parentDataList.get(position);

   holder.mTextView.setText(sData.getParentTitle());

    boolean isExpandable = sData.isExpanded();
    holder.expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

    holder.mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.getContext()));
    holder.mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    holder.mRecyclerView.setAdapter(bAdapter);

    holder.mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        sData.setExpanded(!sData.isExpanded());
        nestedList = sData.getSubList();
        notifyItemChanged(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
    });
}
```

**It did Not work as I expected.**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfitabilityRegionalAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProfitabilityParentData sData = parentDataList.get(position);
    holder.bind(sData, listener);
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private RelativeLayout expandableLayout;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mLinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        expandableLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.probRegionName);
        mRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profitabilityBranchRecycler);
    }

    public void bind(ProfitabilityParentData item, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mTextView.setText(item.getParentTitle());

        boolean isExpandable = item.isExpanded();
        expandableLayout.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext()));
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(bAdapter);

        mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                item.setExpanded(!item.isExpanded());
                listener.onItemClick(item);
                getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Set data from Activity**

```
    adapter = new ProfitabilityRegionalAdapter(getApplicationContext(), sData -> {
        adapter.setSubList(sData.getSubList());
    });
```

**RecyclerView class**

```
public void setSubList(ArrayList<ProfitabilityChildData> subList) {
    this.nestedList = subList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.

With listener.onItemClick, which is inside ViewHolder pass the getAbsoluteAdapterPosition like follow,

```
         mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int absoluteAdapterPosition = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();

                if (parentDataList.get(absoluteAdapterPosition).isExpanded()) {

                    parentDataList.get(absoluteAdapterPosition).setExpanded(false);
                    notifyItemChanged(absoluteAdapterPosition);

                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < parentDataList.size(); i++) {

                        if (parentDataList.get(i).isExpanded() && absoluteAdapterPosition != i) {
                            parentDataList.get(i).setExpanded(false);
                            notifyItemChanged(i);
                        }
                    }

                    parentDataList.get(absoluteAdapterPosition).setExpanded(true);
                    notifyItemChanged(absoluteAdapterPosition);

                }

                listener.onItemClick(item, getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());

            }
        });
```

Then

```
public void setSubList(ArrayList<ProfitabilityChildData> subList, int absoluteAdapterPosition) {
    this.nestedList = subList;
    notifyItemChanged(absoluteAdapterPosition);
}
```